# googlemap is not show on emulator

Tags: android

**Xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
 package com.example.googlemap;
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint; 
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

 import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;
//@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
      //  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         //       .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))   .getMap();
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(KIEL)
            .title("Kiel")
            .snippet("Kiel is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

}

}
```

**Manifest**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.googlemap"
  android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />


<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlemap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCcdbqI_CdaghJQ7VTeXIE1djmnlfZq_Qs" />
  </application>

</manifest>
```

but code is not working, 
error like this

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemap/com.example.googlemap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: full logcat stacktrace please.?

Comment: did you add the google play service lib in your project?

Comment: are you trying to run in emulator or device?

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal Question title clearly specifies emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The `Google Map v2` requires the `Google Play Services` to run and AFAIK the emulator doesn't contains the `Google Play Services` so you can not run the google map in your emulator.

To use the Google Maps Android API v2 in your app, you will first need to install the Google Play services SDK.

For more details check out [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your emulator support Google api.

if not than launch new emulator including Google api and run your code with this new emulator.

Comment: I don't agree with your answer.. see Grishu's answer

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pratik check if your Google Play Service Lib has been added to your project first.

If it is already in your project, it is probably because your minSDKversion is only 8 and not at the minimum of 11 for MapFragment to work, and hence instead of using MapFragment you will need to be using SupportMapFragment instead.

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

needs to be changed to SupportMapFragment 
and so does :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```